# PHP INSERT in MySQL 3000 rows

Tags: php, mysql

To write to the MySQL database 3000 lines.

```
INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("1", "test");
INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("2", "test");
INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("3", "test");

...

INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("3000", "test");
```

How to share request for parts that the database didn't hang up?

Comment: I really cannot understand your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you have 3000 rows to insert but don't want to write them all out? If so use this:

```
$insert = '';
$count = 1;
while ($count <= 3000) {
  $insert .= "('$count', 'test'), ";
  $count++;
}

$insert = substr($insert, 0, -2);

INSERT INTO test (`id`, `test`) VALUES $insert;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group multiple `INSERT` statements into one single statement like the following.

```
INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("1", "test"), ("2", "test"), ("3", "test");
```

This should reduce the amount of queries sent to the server.

Furthermore, if it hangs up your database, you may use the keyword `DELAYED` ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html)). This caches the inserts until the database can afford to insert them. More immediate queries can preceede your inserts and thus delay them. Important to note here is, that you only have your data in the table eventually and not immediatly.

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO test (id, test) VALUES ("1", "test"), ("2", "test"), ("3", "test");
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if this is what you're asking for, but to combine multiple inserts into one query, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, test) VALUES
  ("1", "test"),
  ("2", "test"),
  ("3", "test");
```

this should drastically speed up your script.

Comment: take care not to cross the limit, for some db limit is 1000 rows per multiple insert query, find for mysql